# IDEDeferredInitializationErrorDomain error while opening XCode on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, virtualbox, deferred

On my Windows 8.1 PC and i am running Mac OS Sierra using Virtual Box. I installed XCode on Mac OS Sierra. However, when i open XCode i am getting the below error. Can you provide any directions, please? Thank you folks!

"**The operation couldn't be completed. IDEDeferredInitializationErrorDomain error
1.)**"

Comment: just go to app store update OSX and restart, should resolve.

Comment: It did resolve the issue. You saved me a ton of hours! Thank you so much!

Comment: ill submit as an answer please do accept and upvote :)

Comment: I have accepted it as the answer. However, my upvote did not get displayed since i have less than 15 reps :(.

Comment: It's okay good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just go to app store update `OSX` and restart, should resolve.